# Windows 10 Boot error 0xc000000f

Tags: windows-10, boot

my computer can't boot, I'm gettimg aboot error stating that it meeds to be repairedon Boot/BCD with the same error code that is on the title.

I'll be straight honest with the background and how it happened. After I got stuck in a boot loop caused by a failed Windows update (an update that was for weeks trying to install and always crashed and rolled back. Yesterday it got looped on rolling back, with no access to windows or safe mode), I was trying to somehow recover access to it. My brother told me to try to boot and repair (apparently the fix relied on deleting a damaged registry). He gave me a bootable usb with windows. However it was windows 7 and in my ignorance I tried the repair option on there. As it stated that it had detected errors in the boot and offered an automactic fix assumed it was a generic fix. Big mistake. It said that it failed, so I assumed that it didn't do anything. The rest of the repair options were either ones I didn't know how to use or I had the certainty that wouldn't help. I restarted the computer just to be greeted byt the message I stated at the beginning.

I kept looking for a solution, bought a new usb drive with more storage to set it up with the official windows 10 boot installer, because out of all solutions I found online it was the only viable one. When I got it to boot from the usb and after it loaded, the first message that appears is the following:

(Title: Windows Setup)
It looks like you started an upgrade and booted from installation media. If you want to continue with the upgrade, remove the media from your PC and click Yes. If you want to perform a clean installation instead, click No
(Yes)(No)

Clicking Yes just reboots the computer and I go back to the boot error. So I press No, choose my language and go to Repair. Two options show up, Troubleshoot and Turn off your PC. In troubleshoot I'm able to use the command prompt (Startup Repair option just fails) so I tried following the steps I found online to my problem.

I tried all of the bootrec commands, with these results:
BOOTREC /FIXMBR - operation completed successfully

BOOTREC /FIXBOOT - element not found

BOOTREC /REBUILDBCD - It finds my installation, and when I try to add it to boot list it says Element not found

BOOTREC /SCANOS - operation completed succesfully. Disk C is listed as F.

I also tried deleting the boot folder and building it again resulting in the message: "Failure when attempting to copy boot files."

I'm quite desperate and could use an answer that doesn't involve reinstalling windows, thanks :(

Comment: try **bcdboot c:\windows /s c:**

Comment: Failed at first, but when I tried with F: it worked perfectly and it also fixed the boot loop issues. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bcdboot f:\windows /s f:

The user commented that a variation of my suggestion worked.

Bcdboot - Bcd boot file creation and repair tool.

Most systems have a hidden system partition containing boot files.  This utility add the existing windows install to that boot menu.

Comment: For the uninitiated among us, could you provide a wee bit more detail as to what exactly this command does?